# TypeScript error Argument of type '(response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: void) => void | PromiseLike<void>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typeerror

I got type this problem with the following code:

"Argument of type '(response: IResponse) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: void) => void | PromiseLike'".

And problem this the check() function.

Could you please help me?
I've got really no ideas how to fix.
Thanks!

```html
interface IResponse {
    isChecked: boolean;
}
type TResponse = IResponse;

.....

function dispatchAsync<TResponsePayload>(dispatch: Dispatch, actionType: string, asyncCall: () => Promise<TResponsePayload>): any;

....

check = async () => {
        const {actions, param} = this.props;
        await actions.getInfoById(param.id).then(
            (response: IResponse) => {
                this.setState({isChecked: response.isChecked});
            }
        );
    };

.....

getInfoById = async (id: string): Promise<void> =>
        dispatchAsync<TPermission>(this.dispatch, CHECK_ACTION, async () => {
            return await this.service.getInfoById(id);
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To explain a little bit more, the TypeScript error tells you in another words that you cannot put a function that expects an argument in place of a function that doesn't expect any argument whatsoever.
Imagine code like this:

```js
const myArg = (param: number) => setState(param + 5);

const caller = (arg: () => void) => arg();

caller(myArg);
```

Here is pretty obvious the `caller` won't provide any arguments when calling it's argument.  Therefore calling the `caller` with `myArg` will result in an error thrown inside the `myArg` as it won't receive the argument it expects.

In your example the `getInfoById` returns `Promise<void>`. That means the `then` method will **not** provide any argument to the provided callback. That is the root cause.
You can fix it by telling the TypeScript that `getInfoById` actually returns something inside the promise (in this case I assume it is the `IResponse` type).
Like so:

```js
getInfoById = async (id: string): Promise<IResponse> =>
        dispatchAsync<TPermission>(this.dispatch, CHECK_ACTION, async () => {
            return await this.service.getInfoById(id);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at your code below:

```js
getInfoById = async (id: string): Promise<void> =>
    dispatchAsync<TPermission>(this.dispatch, CHECK_ACTION, async () => {
        return await this.service.getInfoById(id);
});
```

You can change `void` in your  `Promise<void>` with `any` or your spesific data type.

Because you can use return if you use `void`.